# How to change react-native-mathjax default background white color?

Tags: react-native, mathjax

I want to change the background color of the MathJax component. How can I do it? I tried few different solution but they won't work for me. I added custom style for 'mathJaxOptions' but it will changed only formula area color.

My code as follows, please help me to resolve this problem.

```
const mmlOptions = {
      styles: {
        '#formula': {
          'background-color': '#212121',
          color: '#000000',
          padding: 8,
        },
      },
      messageStyle: 'none',
      extensions: ['tex2jax.js'],
      jax: ['input/TeX', 'output/HTML-CSS'],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [
          ['$', '$'],
          ['\\(', '\\)'],
        ],
        displayMath: [
          ['$$', '$$'],
          ['\\[', '\\]'],
        ],
        processEscapes: true,
      },
      TeX: {
        extensions: ['AMSmath.js', 'AMSsymbols.js', 'noErrors.js', 'noUndefined.js'],
      },
    };
```

```
<MathJax
            html={props?.tnode?.init?.domNode?.children[0].data}
            mathJaxOptions={mmlOptions}
            hasIframe={true}
            enableBaseUrl={true}
            color={'red'}
          />
```

change the background color of react-native-mathjax library